# Is there a name for this?

Tags: php

I don't know if this is something specific to the company I used to work at, but they used a template system that made use of code snippets like this:

```
<img src="{!imagelink /!}" />
```

The image link is entered in another form and then basically appears in that part of the template.

Is this part of PHP? Or is it part of a widely used PHP framework?

Comment: now im not too familiar with all possible php syntaxes but Ive never seen it

Comment: @jonathanHeindl I have the suspicion it's something custom made, but I just wanted to make sure.

Comment: Yeah, never seen that one before either, may be custom made. Try doing a regex search for it in the code base: `!(\w+)(.?+)\/!` or something like that or better yet: `!.*\/!`. You should be able to figure out how you company injects data like that.

Comment: It isn't a part of PHP syntax for sure. Must be some framework or template(probably Smarty plugin, but not sure).